# jquery error when trying to get window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

this is all new to me, so excuse me in advance. My intention is to use jQuery in order dynamically compute the width of the window whenever changes. I want a global variable that stores this width in order to access it in other sections. I am using d3.js in the rest of my code in order to make a chart that takes up the entire width of the window, and will hopefully contract/expand when the window is resized. When I run the code and resize the window, the shows the following error: `'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'`

In my header...

```
<script src="d3/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

followed by...

```
var wi = $(window).width();

var windowResizeCallback = function(){

    wi = $(window).width();
    console.log('Window has been resized.  New width = '+ wi + 'px');

}

    $(window).on('resize', 'windowResizeCallback');
```

Comment: remove the quotes around the functions name in the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need quotes around the function name. Replace

```
$(window).on('resize', 'windowResizeCallback');
```

with

```
$(window).on('resize', windowResizeCallback);
```